# What should be the value of $p,q,r,s,$ and $t$ so that the following matrix is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

What should be the value of $p,q,r,s,$ and $t$ so that the following matrix is orthogonal?

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  p & q & r \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & q & s \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & t \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

I tried to solve this problem and here's what I got.

Let the given matrix be matrix $A$. Hence,

$$AA^{t}=I$$

So,

$$ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  p & q & r \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & q & s \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & t \\
  \end{array} } \right]
 \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  p & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
q & q & 0 \\
r & s & t \\
  \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

Here are the equations I got.

$$p^2 + q^2 +r^2 = 1$$
$$ q^2 + s^2 = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$ t^2=\frac{2}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}p+q^2+rs=0$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}p+tr=0$$
$$st=-\frac{1}{3}$$

After this, I am stuck in this problem.
I can only find the value of $t$ and $s$.

Comment: It's easier to use $A^tA=I$ rather than $AA^t=I$.

Comment: @user1551, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @user1551, I would sincerely appreciate if you could share your answers and solution to the given problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. Solving this problem is your responsibility, not mine, but I will give you a hint. Recall that $A$ is orthogonal if its three columns are mutually orthogonal unit vectors. Let $A=\pmatrix{u&v&w}$. You may (1) determine $q$ using $\|v\|=1$, (2) determine $p$ using $u\perp v$, (3) determine the relationship between $r,s$ and $t$ using $w\perp v$. Finally, you may (4) determine the vector $(r,s,t)$ (up to a sign) using $\|w\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. was able to solve it using your first hint.